# How to add two floating action button on top-right of parrent layout (half insidelayout, and half outside), and show on click

Tags: android, floating-action-button

i want to when user click on certain row of  custom tableview to  show two floating buttons on  top-right position of parrent layout, but to be shown half in layout, and half outside layout.

Here is example:

[image]

Consider that bottom layout is in my case row of table view,

Here is layout where i want to add fab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainAddEditIcons"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="visible">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tvLAyout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u share in image for that

Comment: please add the design you wanted in image format so we all can easily help you

Comment: See edit please

Comment: Use anchor tag of floating action button for this purpose

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml. if you are not looking for collapsing toolbar use constraint layout. Avoid nesting layouts if possible

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainAddEditIcons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tvLAyout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="@color/colorblueLight"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="NIlu" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tvLAyout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/l_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/floating_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrange"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tvLAyout1"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nilu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nilu2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/nilu"
            android:background="@color/colorGray"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/nilu"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                app:elevation="2dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I always wondered if i was the only one who used negative margin hack to get that layout , its good to know that i am not alone :D

Comment: How to change this to be wrap content please?

Comment: I need witdh of layout where text is to be wrap content

Comment: Sir in this case in grey layout is only one textview and width of grey layout need to be wrap content,  and above that layout fab...

Comment: @NikolasBozic check the solution of using `CoordinatorLayout` and you can remove weights

Comment: @NikolasBozic Try something by yourself. this is the solution now arrange this by your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0E0E0">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:alpha="1.0"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:src="@drawable/food_1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_up" />

        <!-- Back button -->

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_show_rating_dialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/top_card"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24px" />

    <!-- Ratings -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_card"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="28dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_rating" />

</RelativeLayout>
```